# Android startActivityForResult, setResult, onActivityResult not called

Tags: android, start-activity, onactivityresult

I started a phone call Activity requesting for result:

```
    Intent intentcall = new Intent();
intentcall.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intentcall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
this.startActivityForResult(intentcall, REQUEST_SLIPDROP_ICON_OFF);
```

And then set the result in phone call listener like this:

```
    private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{
     public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

         super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

         switch (state) {
             case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                                   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                                   break;
```

Finally I want to turn off the icon in onActivityResult, but nothing happens.

```
    switch (requestCode) {

    case REQUEST_SLIPDROP_ICON_OFF:
        Log.d("request icon off", "request icon off");

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {     

            changeMenuItem(R.id.fall, R.drawable.fall);
            slipAndDropIconOn = false;

        } 

        break;
```

Anything wrong?  Please advise!  thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this action returns a result so calling `startActivityForResult` is no different to calling `startActivity`

Note here: output = None.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL

Comment: I use ACTION_CALL as the intent.  Even this intent does not return any result, but I set the result explicitly since I was listen to the phone state with the following code:    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                                   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);

Comment: ACTION_CALL also has no return value. You are setting the result in your listener not in the dialer activity. It is the activity that would need the result setting. You do not have access to that. According to the docs, PhoneStateListener has no setResult method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

Comment: I see.  I think I get it.  Everytime I call setResult() it will trigger the onActivityResult() call back.  But my code to turn the icon off won't get executed because the condition case REQUEST_SLIPDROP_ICON_OFF: is not met.  Why?  I started the activity with this requestCode already.  BTW, PhoneStateListener is a inner class of the activity.  Any other way to achieve the result I want?

Comment: No it appears you don't get it. There is no callback. This intent does not return a result. onActivityResult will NEVER be called because the Activity that contains the dialer never sets a result as I already stated in my previous comments. It is the dialer that would need to setResult for this to work.

Comment: So basically I don't have access to the dialer code, I won't be able to setResult for that activity?  Even though I setResult on phoneListener, it's not what I want because I originally started the dialer activity.

Comment: By the way, does it matter if I call finish() after setResult()?

Comment: setResult is setting the result for YOUR activity. It will only ever be used if you start YOUR activity with a call to StartActivityForResult. From the description of your issue, I do not believe you need to setResult at all. Similarly calling finish will close your activity. If that is what you want, then go for it.

Comment: All this is explained in the documentation. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Comment: but, in my case onActivityResult is getting called but i always get RESULT_CANCELED.

Comment: Akash. Please open your own question and post your code.