# Multiple phone calls from android app

Tags: android, cordova

I'm implementing a function where an outgoing alarm is triggered, f.e. If the phone falls down and doesn't move for 60s afterwards. Then, between 1-5 numbers should be called. Example of how it should work:

> 1. Phone falls down and doesnt move for 60s
> 2. Number 1 is called
> 3. Number 1 doesn't accept call in 20s
> 4. Number 2 is called
> 5. Number 2 doesn't accept call in 20s
> 6. Number 3 is called
> 7. Number 3 accepts call, alarm is being terminated

The alarm is triggered correctly, and I can make a call. But I couldn't find anything on how to determine if a call was accepted after x seconds, and how to start a new call then. Any help / sources?

**Edit:**
Via the [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) I'm now able to see if the call was cancelled. However if it's not, I can't get the actual state, so I don't know if it's still ringing, if it's actually calling or if it has gone to the mailbox. In the description of the [CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519094/onactivityresult-not-getting-called-for-intent-action-call-after-user-exits-th) it's pretty clear that you can't see wheter the call was answered or the number has just been dialed. Is there any workaround for that, maybe even with rooting the phone or something like that? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: you might have to depend upon call logs, after 20s you will need to checkout last dial call and its call duration.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this isn't possible.

The documentation for [Intent.ACTION_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL) states that it doesn't return an output (at least I guess that's what the oh-so-helpful "`Output: nothing`" comment means).

Similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569089/android-startactivityforresult-setresult-onactivityresult-not-called) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519094/onactivityresult-not-getting-called-for-intent-action-call-after-user-exits-th) have not gotten any useful positive responses.

Answer (score 0):

While using an intent makes it NOT possible since you can't check the state, that's NOT the way you should call the telephony service since you want your program to be in control. The best way is to this is to: 
a) enable telephony permissions in your app:
    
    
b) instantiate the Telephony manager class in your activity, then 
c) handle Android call states dial/listen in your activity to store the previous state. If it was 'ringing' and current state is idle a they cancelled the call. If the current state is off-hook and the previous state was ringing, they answered the call. See a working sample here:
http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/08/android-call-state-listener-example.html

Comment: Unfortunately this is not helping for my requirements. CALL_STATE_RINGING is only for incoming calls. The moment an outgoing call is made the state is CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK, until the phone is hung up and the state is CALL_STATE_IDLE again.